# MySQL database query solution

Tags: mysql

Given database schema are as following

```
employee(employee_name, street, city);
works(employee_name,company_name,salary);
company(company_name,city);
```

Now i need a query on it
1.Find all employees who live in New York city but their company is not in New York city.

Comment: Any query that you tried so far ?

Comment: That looks like a Specification and **not a question**. We dont work from specs, its not a **get your free code here** site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use The following query

```
select e.employee_name from employee e
Join Works w on e.employee_name = w.employee_name
Join company c on w.company_name = c.company_name
Where e.city like "New York" and c.city not like "New York"
order by e.employee_name
```

Comment: What city is `like 'New York'`? Chicago?

Answer (score 0):

please try below query

```
select emp.employee_name  from employee emp left join works w on emp.employee_name =w.employee_name left join company c on w.company_name = c.company_name

where isnull( emp.city,'') like 'New York' and  isnull( company.city,'')!= 'New York'
```

Comment: your query didn't worked.  then i used following query....select e.employee_name from employee e Join Works w on e.employee_name = w.employee_name Join company c on w.company_name = c.company_name Where e.city like "New York" and c.city not like "New York" order by e.employee_name

Answer (score -1):

select e.employee_name from employee e Join Works w on e.employee_name = w.employee_name Join company c on w.company_name = c.company_name Where e.city like "New York" and c.city not like "New York" order by e.employee_name